# Given a function, how can I get the arguments passed to it?

Tags: python, boolean-logic

Here's what I am trying to do. I have a `Prop` class defined as this:

```
class Prop:
    def __init__(self, val, name=None):
        self.val=val
        self.name=name
    def getVal(self):
        return self.val
    def giveName(self, newname):
        self.name=newname
    def getName(self, name):
        return self.name
    def changeVal(self, newval):
        if type(newval)!=bool:
            raise ValueError("You are trying to assign non-boolean value to the proposition")
        else:
            self.val=newval
```

As you can understand, `Prop` objects should be regarded as propositions with boolean value ascribed to each one of them. Also I have defined a standard boolean function, implication:

```
def impl(p, q):
    if p.getVal()==True and q.getVal()==False:
        return Prop(False)
    else:
        return Prop(True)
```

Now what I want to do is to define a function which will take some expression like this `impl(impl(p,q), r)` as the first of its arguments and a list of `Prop`objects (`[p,q,r]`) as the second one and check if this expression is true in regard with the propositions in the list. One important thing: if there's no proposition in the list which was mentioned in the expression, our program should regard this proposition as a false one. How can I do that?

Comment: You need a class that represents formulas, not a function that immediately evaluate a formula.

Comment: You're also likely to need a way to parse formulas.